# How to hide some listview context menu (loaded from xml) items?

Tags: java, android, listview, contextmenu

I inflate my context menu for listview from xml like this:

```
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.meni, menu);
}
```

But based on some data in my listview row (i know how to get that data), sometimes i want to hide some menu items.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.itemId);
    item.setVisible(false);
```

after inflating the menu.